# GSON, disable deserializaton from specific field/variable and save json as string

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

How to get JSON as string from variable `tags` after deserializating?

json file as example:

```
{
"first_name": "John",
"last_name" : "Well",
"tags": {"1001": "author", "1002": "signer"}
}
```

class Person:

```
Class Person{
  String first_name;
  String last_name;

  String tags; // here should be json as string
}
```

Method to calling funciton deseralization json.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
gson.fromJson(txt, Person.class);
```

Error:

```
10-04 07:33:28.035 26156-26481/pl.xxxE/AndroidRuntime: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 4 column 9
```

** UPDATED 1 **

Answer from @dtx12:

```
Class Person{
  String first_name;
  String last_name;
  JSONObject tags; // but result {}
}
```

Also that answer wasn't helpfully because of empty result. But like that should be stopped in deserialization's progress ...I am talking about performance usinng mobile app with deserializating an 1000+ objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JsonObject` instead of `String` and then call method `toString()` on this field (you can make getter for this purposes for example)

Comment: hmm, I have tried to use `JsonObject` isntead of `String`, but he results only "{}"

Comment: Your JsonObject should be imported from gson namespace, you probably imported it from wrong package.

Answer (score 0):

Like **dtx12** said You can do the following:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson( jsonString, JsonObject.class);
String tags = jsonObject.get("tags").toString();
```

Comment: I meant changing field type in class, not your variant.